# Are coproducts right adjoint of diagonal functor on opposite category?

Tags: category-theory, adjoint-functors

Continuing my recent investigations into adjunctions, I've come to understand how products are defined in terms of adjunctions.  A category $\mathscr{C}$ has products if there is a right adjoint to the diagonal function $\Delta\colon \mathscr{C} \to \mathscr{C}\times\mathscr{C}$, namely $\times\colon \mathscr{C}\times\mathscr{C} \to \mathscr{C}$.  The product of two objects $A$ and $B$ is $\times(A,B)$, more typically denoted $A \times B$.

Now, I know that coproducts are dual to products, and that in the direct way of describing coproducts (i.e., as they're typically presented before adjunctions have been covered),  they're just presented as dual to products:  reverse the arrows in the defining diagram and be done.  As such, I *think* that we can explain coproducts using adjunctions by simply saying that $\mathscr{C}^{\mathbf{op}}$ has products, and to leave it at that.  So:

1. Is this correct?  I'm reasonably confident that it is, but I could be missing some caveat.
2. Is this the typical way to characterize coproducts using adjunctions?  If not, is there a simpler or more direct to do it, while still using adjunctions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\mathbf{C}$ having coproducts is indeed the same thing as saying $\mathbf{C}^\circ$ has products.

Usually, when this style is used, we define coproducts as *left* adjoints to the diagonal. More generally, limits are right adjoints to the generalized diagonal $\mathbf{C} \to \mathbf{C}^J$, and colimits are left adjoints.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!  I'm almost ready to accept, but can you clarify how you mean that the coproducts are _left_ adjoints to the diagonal?  The diagonal functor still has $\mathscr{C}$ as domain and $\mathscr{C}\times\mathscr{C}$ as codomain, and so it's the $\lor\colon \mathscr{C}\times\mathscr{C}\to \mathscr{C}$ that's brings us back to $\mathscr{C}$, which is the category that actually has the coproduct object, isn't it?

Comment: Oh, nevermind.  I just spent 30 seconds at the whiteboard and I see what you mean.  Without considering $\mathscr{C}^{\mathbf{op}}$ at all, coproducts are simply the left adjoint of the diagonal.

Comment: If this is a trivial question (maybe I just need to spend a little more time at the whiteboard), a simple yes/no will suffice:  does it hold in general that if something if right/left adjoint in the opposite (or dual) category, then it's the same as the left/right adjoint in the non-opposite category?  (If it's non trivial, just say so, and I'll investigate some more.)

Comment: The question is a little off, but what I think you mean to say works out simply from the homset description of adjoint functors, because $$\hom_{\mathbf{C}^\circ}(X,Y) = \hom_{\mathbf{C}}(Y,X)$$ Or by looking at the definition of adjunction in terms of unit and counit and seeing that it is self-dual in an appropriate sense.

Comment: Poor wording on my part aside, that makes sense. Thanks for the clarification!